# How to open a form with a button and automatically assign a value to one of the fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to open a form by clicking a button and I want the form to open with a value written in one of the fields. I could achieve this by just puting the value in the default value of the field. but i want it dynamic in a way that when i open the form with another button,  i want another specified value to show up in the field.

This is the code of the button to open the form FRM_PRODUCT_COMMENT. I want inventory to be wriiten in the field 'Thema'

`'DoCmd.OpenForm "FRM_PRODUCT_COMMENT", WhereCondition:=[THEMA]= "Inventory" , acNormal, , ,acFormAdd`

Also from another button , i want to open the same form with another thing writtten in the field 'Thema'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like so, setting the textbox value afterwards :

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTestForm", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acWindowNormal
Forms("frmTestForm").Controls("txtTextboxTest").Value = "Testing"
```